# Preventing automatic modal in second level container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modals in project. In one page i have 2 containers that, one of them is inside the other one. The outer one has a modal trigger on click event and the inner one has a routing to another page. I can get modal popup if i click on outer container. That's okay but the problem is if i click the smaller container, modal triggered also before routing.

```
<div class="outer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">          
    <a href="somewhere">
        <div class="inner></div>
    </a>                                             
</div>
```

How can i prevent the pop up if i click the inner container. 
I know i can cancel modal if i catch the hover event for inner container but i am looking more bootstrap way.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your html a bit. I have put the link inside the inner div. Then using jquery you can stop propagation.

```
<div class="outer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">      
    sadsdaddsads<br/>
    asdsddsa<br/>

        <div class="inner"><a href="somewhere">asadds</a>  </div>

</div>

       <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.outer > .inner').click(function(e) {
                    //alert("inner div clicked");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });

            });

        </script>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I've also created a css class called 'noModal' and i can give this to any element i want.